# React-boilerplate project won't run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-boilerplate

A javascript react project I've got setup on another machine, won't run on a different machine. The error I get is so uninformative I don't know where to start looking.

```
main.a03af49….js:formatted:1163 Uncaught TypeError: n(...) is not a function
at Object../ (main.a03af49….js:formatted:1163)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.a03af49….js:formatted:328)
at t (main.a03af49….js:formatted:10)
at Object../node_modules/core-js/shim.js (main.a03af49….js:formatted:15555)
at t (main.a03af49….js:formatted:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.a03af49….js:formatted:10588)
at Object../node_modules/babel-polyfill/lib/index.js (main.a03af49….js:formatted:10601)
at t (main.a03af49….js:formatted:10)
at Object../app/app.js (main.a03af49….js:formatted:1210)
at t (main.a03af49….js:formatted:10)
```

The function that is supposedly throwing the above error:

```
"./": function(e, t, n, o) {
    n(o)("observable")
},
```

How do I even begin looking into this problem?

EDIT: Original machine was a debian server 8.6, this one is ubuntu server 16.04.

Comment: Any more details about the differences of these machines? Are they using two different operating systems? In what machine (OS) was the original bundle generated?

Comment: @dogui edited original question with additional info